# Select Checkbox based on attribute value

Tags: jquery

I have a ckeckbox like this

```
<input data-index="7" data-name="Sector-108" type="checkbox">
```

i want to **uncheck this checkbox** based on data-name attribete selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
$('[data-name=Sector-108]').prop('checked',true);
```

You can use [attribute selector starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) wild card to get all the elements having name like `Sector-`

```
$('[data-name^=Sector-]').prop('checked',false);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[data-name=Sector-108]).removeProp('checked');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it as below.

```
$('input').hasAttr('data-name').attr('checked','checked');
```

Comment: i want to select based on data-name attr value.Lets I have Sector-108 then how can i find the checkbox and dessable it?